# Custom ActionBar is partially visible

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ABS and here is my custom view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/list" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/create_dcyde" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my onCreate

```
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

If I reduce bottom padding of RelativeLayout to 10dp I can see TextViews partially.But I want at least 20dp bottom padding to relative layout to look it good. But at 20dp TxtView get disappear. Am I exceeding any height limit of ActionBar?

[Screenshot](http://s8.postimage.org/qm9453oyd/action_bar.png)

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would be a nice help for ppl to see what is going on.

Comment: Could not attach the image. Not enough points. Also, there is slight gap of 2dp on left side is there. I am also going to add logo in centre in top RelativeLayout. Is this right approach for such action-bars. I don't want to user tabs as they are deprecated and action items by default align to left.

Comment: I think the ActionBar has a set height, which will not stretch/shrink around custom view.

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Why don't you just take away the TextViews, so your actionbar will fit. and add some custom (white looking) tabs. 
Actionbar has tabs too, which aren't deprecated like TabHost.

Comment: I think I should try this. I actually thought of this but don't want to use Fragment. let me this and will update. thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using Fragments, it's actually the preferred way :)

Comment: Started doing it and ran into issues [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151931/how-to-distribute-tabs-on-actionbar-width-evenly)