# How to distribute TABs on actionbar width evenly?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Raised [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134731/custom-actionbar-is-partially-visible) question and working on the suggestion to use TABS with custom ActionBar on TOP. Created three TABS but they are aligned to left and plenty of room is available to stretch.

How can I distribute TABS evenly on width? I am using ABS.

Answer (score 0):

You can find demo's of all functionality of ABS in Jake Wharton's github. 
The tab example is here, and should take care of everything in a couple of lines.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java

Comment: This is what I am doing...but TABS (3) align to left side automatically. I think I need to override styles to do this. Any idea?

Comment: There is a styled tabs example there too ;)

Comment: Yes. But that is only styled tabs. What I want is styled tab with custom action bar. Anyway I have tried the mix version of these two and get [this](http://s14.postimage.org/qkbu6bp29/action_bar_tab_and_custom_bar.png)  which is very similar to [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190078/how-to-create-android-actionbar-with-custom-view-and-tabs)

Comment: Stuck. tried and tried but no success. Please give some clue on this.